# why does 'Doc2Vec' object has no attribute 'n_similarity' ,most_similar, relative cosine_similarity from?? this is while calculating the scores

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, doc2vec

```
#training a gensim model & finding the cosine similarity

model = Doc2Vec(dm = 1, min_count=1, window=10, sample=1e-4, negative=10,epochs=20)
model.build_vocab(questions_labeled)
model.train(questions_labeled, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)

model.most_similar('good')

doc2vec_scores = []
for i in range(len(questions1_split)):
    score = model.n_similarity(questions1_split[i],questions2_split[i])
    doc2vec_scores.append(score)
```

Comment: To have a fair chance of letting answerers deduce what's gone wrong, you should always include inside your question text the *full multiline error message* you are seeing, including any 'traceback' info shown (with filenames/line-numbers/code involved). You can edit the question to add this. Also, your code would ideally give some idea of what's in the various variables used (but not defined) in related lines of code, like `questions_labeled` and `questions1_split`. (I've also improved the readability of your code by placing it inside a `\`\`\`` block.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.